# comment is cut in half in algorithm and unwanted return to the line

Tags: algorithms, comments

there is a return to the line when I am using the comment "default". I would like the same comment to be used but I don't want the text of the comment to be divided in two and I do not want a return the line, I want the full word to be printed at that location

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf,review]{acmart}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill // \textit{#1}}

\newcommand{\rtm}[1][m,r]{\text{rtm\textsubscript{m}[\text{#1}]}}
\newcommand{\mh}[1]{
  {\color{green!70!black} MH: #1}}
 \newcommand{\cmd}[1]{
  {\color{blue} CMD: #1}} 
  \newcommand{\rev}[1]{
  {\color{purple} REV: #1}} 

\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pc}{0.5pc}{0pc}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pc}{0pc}{0pc}

\begin{document}


\title{test}


\author{Authors not shown due to the double-blind regulation}

\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, et al.}


\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\setcopyright{none}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}
\pagestyle{plain}

\maketitle



\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Step 3-T Refinement}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \FORALL {r in requirements}  
        \FORALL {m in methods}  
        \IF {rtm$_m$[m,r]==U \AND rtm$_c$[m.class,r]==T}
        \IF {atLeast1T(rtm$_c$[m.collectCallers().classes,r])\hfill\COMMENT{\textit{\textit{Default}}}
        \newline 
        \AND atLeast1T(rtm$_c$[m.collectCallees().classes,r])\newline
        \AND zeroNs(rtm$_m$[m.collectCallers(),r])\newline
        \AND zeroNs(rtm$_m$[m.collectCallees(),r])\newline
    }

        \STATE  rtm$_m$[m,r]=T

        \ELSIF {        isEmpty(m.callees) \hfill\COMMENT{\textit{Leaf}}
        \newline
                \AND atLeast1T(rtm$_c$[m.collectCallers().classes,r])\newline
                \AND zeroNs(rtm$_m$[m.collectCallers(), r])\newline
                }

            \STATE  rtm$_m$[m,r]=T

            \ELSIF {allTs(rtm$_c$[m.collectCallers().classes,r]) \hfill\COMMENT{\textit{Default}}
            \newline
            \AND zeroNs(rtm$_m$[m.collectCallers(), r])\newline     
            \AND zeroNs(rtm$_m$[m.collectCallees(), r])}

        \STATE  rtm$_m$[m,r]=T


            \ELSIF {allTs(rtm$_c$[m.collectCallees().classes,r]) \hfill\COMMENT{\textit{Default}}
            \newline
            \AND zeroNs(rtm$_m$[m.collectCallers(), r])\newline     
            \AND zeroNs(rtm$_m$[m.collectCallees(), r])}

        \STATE  rtm[m,r]=T
        \ENDIF
        \ENDIF
        \ENDFOR
        \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
    \label{alg:Step3}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could it be possible that your algorithm is just too wide for the twocolumn layout and therefore linebreaks inside of your comments are added?

Comment: how to fix that? I don't want it to break

Comment: Add the comments on lines by themselves as `\STATE\hfill\COMMENT{text}`

Comment: I want these comments at the right of the if statement and I don't want them at the level of \STATE

Comment: it sill breaks when I use \STATE\hfill\COMMENT{text}, problem is not solved